# Hide Svelte component from outside script

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I am importing a third-party Svelte3 component with several children. For the sake of example, the third-party component looks like the following:

```html
<script>
  import Child1 from './third-party/Child1.svelte';
  import Child2 from './third-party/Child2.svelte';
</script>

<div>
  <Child1/>
  <Child2/>
</div>
```

What would be the cleanest way to hide one of the children components **from within my app** (or from the dev console) given that:

1. it has no easily identifiable CSS selector, and
2. I cannot modify the third-party code?

In Vue, I would use the root instance, but is this possible in Svelte?

Thank you very much!

Guido

Comment: You could hide `nth-child` of third party? [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/13e88f7b031543e594bf0bc94dc19774?version=3.46.1)

Comment: What do you mean by hide from the app and the dev console? Remove it from the DOM? Just visually hide it?

Comment: @pilchard Thanks for the suggestion! However, I cannot rely on the ordering of the elements.

Comment: @johannchopin By "hiding" I mean visually hide, although removing from DOM would also work for my purpose. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no clean way. Messing with the DOM from outside a component is a hacky solution and can lead to unpredictable results.

This is a feature the **third party** needs to add to their **public api.**

An option for the  third party is to expose the feature is via props using **$set** using the [component api](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api-$set):

```html
// App.svelte
<script>
import Child1 from './third-party/Child1.svelte';
import Child2 from './third-party/Child2.svelte';

export let child2Visible = true;
</script>

<div>
    <Child1/>
    {#if child2Visible}
      <Child2/>
    {/if}
</div>
```

```
// my-app.js
import App from "./App.svelte";

window.app = new App({target});
```

```
// From dev console
app.$set({ child2Visible: false })
```

Another way for the third party is to expose a way for setting a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store) value which could toggle some of the ui.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Alas it does not solve my dilemma, but it is much appreciated as it shows the clean way to go for the third party.